# How to render simple 2d text in openGL with delphi?

Tags: delphi, opengl, text, fonts

I am trying to find a way to display a simple text on an openGL form in Delphi.
I tried this with Labels, but they were not showing up. I'm guessing that the openGL window was rendered on top of it, so I tried to call `Label1.BringToFront;` but this didn't work.
I also heard of a library called freetype, but I couldn't find info, how to implement it in Delphi.
What is the simplest way to render out text on an openGL form in Delphi?

Comment: Draw a quad on screen with a texture of a letter mapped to it. You can create one texture with your entire font and modify the quad's UVs to draw the right letter. Repeat the sequence for words.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use opengl's wglfontbitmaps

```
 const numberchar =128
allocate:

 wglMakeCurrent(FDC, FRC);
 FFontBase := glGenLists(numberchar);
 SelectObject(FDC, FFont.Handle);                              
 wglUseFontBitmaps(FDC,0,128, FFontBase);                     


draw(atext:ansistring);
 glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);                             
 glListBase(FFontbase);  
  glCallLists(Length(aText), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Pansichar(aText)); list
 glPopAttrib;                                           

free:
 glDeleteLists(FFontBase, numberchar);
```

The draw code is only partial. Best to look for tutorials for similar code.

Note this will only give you basic unscaled font. For fancy text effects, indeed, freetype is the most common route.

A good place to start with Delphi and opengl is http://www.delphigl.com/ Mostly German, but some English boards too.

An alternative (provided that you have D2010+) is to look in the direction of **DirectX**. D2010+ comes with a directx context component.

Comment: -1 because it's tied to Windows and does not work in modern OpenGL core profiles.

Comment: -1 also, window-system bindings are not part of the OpenGL spec. They are related, but the core spec specifies neither GLX, nor WGL nor AGL - let alone EGL. To be fair, FreeType is a good hint and there are several solutions out there using the lib.

Comment: Those reasons for the downvotes are a bit silly if the implementation is for Delphi.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: Delphi or not, WGL font bitmaps will not work with modern OpenGL core profiles, because all the functions related to them (glRasterPos, glDrawPixels, glBitmap) have been removed. Also there's a port of Delphi for Linux (Kylix / Lazarus).

Comment: Kylix is dead for close to a decade, and the guy said Delphi, not Lazarus or Kylix. As far as the profiles go, afaik it works just fine with OpenGL3 contexts. So my answer "the simplest" still stands IMHO. Still, it wouldn't hurt if you provided a detailed freetype based answer.